# Meteor: Trying to serve a static file outside of /public

Tags: meteor

TLDR;
How can one serve a static file through iron router? If I place a file in /public it bypasses all the hooks I could use in iron router.

Long version:
I need to log all requests to an image file. Specifically I'd like to persist to Mongodb the querystring in every request such as 'a=1&b=2' from http://domain.com/cat.png?a=1&b=2.

I don't see a way of doing this in Meteor. But I could use the iron router hooks such as params.query . Except that any static files in /public get served by Meteor's handler, and bypasses iron router.

(I'm looking to use up to date apis. There are lots of posts here pre meteor 1.0 and pre ironrouter)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You have full access to the request and response objects of the HTTP request, and you can even wire up arbitrary connect middleware.

Here is my solution using the latter, serving from the `/tmp` directory:

```js
var serveStatic = Meteor.npmRequire('serve-static');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var serve = serveStatic('/tmp');
    // NOTE: this has to be an absolute path, since the relative
    // project directories change upon bundling/production

    Router.onBeforeAction(serve, {where: 'server'});

    Router.route('/:file', function () {
        this.next();
    }, {where: 'server'});
}
```

To make this work you'll also need the npm package:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

And you'll need to add serve-static to your packages.json file:

```
{
    "serve-static": "1.10.0"
}
```

Afterwards, any file `/tmp/x.xyz` will be available on your `/x.xyz` URL.

Comment: Yes I see how that would work. But I don't see how the query string params I mentioned would cleanly go into a mongo collection.

Comment: Your question was "Trying to serve a static file outside of /public". If there is a separate question, then perhaps that would better be a separate question on stackoverflow too?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fs` to server any file:

```
Router.route('/static/:filename', function (){
  var fs = Npm.require('fs'),
      path = '/tmp/' + this.params.filename; // make sure to validate input here

  // read the file
  var chunk = fs.createReadStream(path);

  // prepare HTTP headers
  var headers = {}, // add Content-type, Content-Lenght etc. if you need
      statusCode = 200; // everything is OK, also could be 404, 500 etc.

  // out content of the file to the output stream
  this.response.writeHead(statusCode, headers);
  chunk.pipe(this.response);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:  Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/tmp/cat.png', even though the file is there. Where does fs look for /tmp/ ?

Comment: @LPG, can you make sure you have rights to read the file? You can try setting full access to the file with `chmod 666 /tmp/cat.png`. fs is looking for '/tmp/' in current root directory which is '/' in most cases however could be different on shared hostings.

Comment: Same error :( I have tried every OS level change. There are some other hacks using node.path , but I feel like that shouldn't need to be done. (btw I'm on OSX yosemite)

Comment: @LPG, maybe things are different on OSX? What if we try to find out what is current directory and what files are available for the script?

Can you list files that are in current directory to find out what is current directory or maybe try list files of '/' or '/tmp' ?
 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback