# Serve static assets and media separately from meteor with nginx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, nginx

Coming from Django I'm accustomed to serving my static assets and media (including uploads) separately from the main wsgi or other app. This flat file structure is easy to navigate and manage.

I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this (serve static assets/media separately) with Meteor.

1. Is there a standard approach?
2. Are there packages that provide this functionality?

My end goals are:

1. to be able to more intuitively navigate all the static assets and media and access them from a publicly accessible URL without having to hot rebuild the meteor app. The "public" folder doesn't do it for me... especially for uploaded media.
2. upload to this system path (which is separate from the main meteor app) either manually when migrating an app or via a custom app/package I write.
3. browse/parse the path from meteor app/package

Comment: did you see my previous answer on a related question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31129568/1087119; you could add collectionsFS with file-system based storage to that and then you should have everything you need.

Comment: I believe my question is more clearly what your answer applies to as his is also asking for logging of requests in his db -  also - my question was specific about serving static assets separately from meteor - your answer still serves from the meteor app as i understand it - (read title of my question)

Comment: well, you are free to ignore my suggestion, it was just a comment, not an answer begging for the bounty ;-) Also, your question body is not even mentioning nginx, but you do ask for "serve static assets/media separately) with Meteor". anyhow, I'm sure someone will answer.

Comment: May I ask about the reasons why you would want this. I know you explained some end goals, but I'm feeling the real motive is missing. Is it for performance or scalability reasons?

Comment: it's partially for performance but mostly because navigating a deployed meteor site within obfuscated subfolder paths is painful - i also have gigabytes of video pre-encoded in a given structure

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you want to achieve. If you have data in a specific folder structure, you can serve it with a separate server (apache/nginx). Just make sure your Meteor app uses the appropriate hrefs to this data served by a different server. In this case, make sure you set the appropriate CORS headers.

Answer (score 11):

If all your static assets have a common path, for instance `/static/...`, then you can tell `nginx` to [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) requests to that path with a directory

```
location /static  {
    alias /path/to/static/assets;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would want this for performance and scalability reasons (see my comment) you should go with a Caching Proxy. Initially the proxy will fetch a static file from the Meteor app directly, but subsequent requests will be served from its cache.

This article ([nginx-caching](https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching/)) is a good read about how to set-up a caching proxy with Nginx in general. Also, Meteorpedia has an [article](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/nginx) explaining how to setup an Nginx cache specifically tailored for a Meteor app.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a file server within your meteor app to serve them using the node `fs` module then serve using something like [Picker](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/picker) or there's an example of adding a connect handler to Meteor [here](http://meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API#WebApp.connectHandlers%20and%20connect) if that doesn't work out.

Meteor will ignore hidden directories by default so you could put the assets inside your app directory if you want in something like `.assets/`, otherwise anywhere on the filesystem that the user running meteor can access.

Here's a working server for text files that I just threw together. You'll need to do `meteor add meteorhacks:picker` first:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  Picker.route('/asset/:name', function(params, req, res) {
    fs.readFile('/home/users/someuser/media/' + params.name, function(err, file) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end(file.toString());
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: that is still within the scope of the meteor project - I want to specify an arbitrary filesystem location eg. meteor project is in /home/users/someuser/greatapp and assets/media are in /home/users/someuser/media

Comment: Ah, I missed that requirement. You can access any files on the filesystem that your user has rights to using fs so could build it to point anywhere, you'd only have problems with the app rebuilding if it was within your app directory. I'll update my answer and add a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your meteor app is at `/www/meteor` and you want to serve static assets from a directory that is outside the `/meteor` tree so that file adds/changes/removes don't cause the app to restart, for example `/www/static`

So first define your Meteor path in nginx normally then define a different *root* for the static path, ex:

```
location /static {
  root /www/static;
}
```

[documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/)