# Serve static content only to logged in users Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am currently storing all my images in the `public` folder and once logged in the user can see all the images listed on the page. But I want it to be so that the user can't access the images if he/she is not logged in.

Right now, if the user types `localhost:3000/image.png` he/she is able to access the images. How do I stop this?

Comment: you can do this following this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31129568/1087119. It's not a duplicate but points you in the right direction. Essentially you can replicate the static-serving behavior for folders other than `public` and then specify your own logic for whom to serve that to.